# How to create a Cover Flow effect in android

Tags: android, coverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a cover flow in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655686/setting-up-a-cover-flow-in-android)

i wish to create a cover flow effect for my android app,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link

its provide library for that

http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Answer (score 2):

I used this code on my project http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

You can adapt it to load the contents from some `datasource`, it's not a hard work.